# Locked IBM 3486 twinax console

Tags: ibm-midrange

So, we have a IBM 3486 twinaxial console that has a lock in the lock position. When we turn on the monitor we see the X and lock on the bottom of the screen indicating that the console is locked. As you may have assumed, we do not have the key. I took the monitor apart and physically unscrewed the lock. I've placed the lock and whatever mechanism is in the back of the lock to the unlock position thinking I could bypass the lock. However, powering on the monitor still showed the lock. Any suggestions on how to unlock this thing without the key (probably lost 2 decades ago), lol? Thanks.

Comment: You have to post a picture of this.  I think cross any wires to lock to complete the circuit.

Comment: What model is the server? If possible, maybe best is to change the console type from twin-ax to LAN console.